# Removing directory structure from R shiny downloadHandler on linux system

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to know if it's possible to remove the tmp folder directory structure from the download file name of my shiny app, and if yes, how please.
My shiny app uses tempfile() to generate a filename in the tempdir() with the initial part of the name given by an input (fieldName_f). This works fine on my Windows computer, e.g. if input$fieldName_f <- 'Paddock1', the filename in the popup window displayed 'Paddock1Report420239b17634.html'.
However, when the codes run on the linux server where my app is hosted, the tmp directory will be appended before my input name, e.g. the output filename will be '_tmp_Rtmp53xNDh_Paddock1Report420239b17634.html', which is undesireable.

I'm wondering if there is a way to set e.g. a junk path to ensure that the folder structure does not get saved in the filename in the downloadHandler please.

Thanks heaps!

```
  frmd <- tempfile('report', tmpdir = tempdir(), fileext = '.Rmd') 
  output$downloadF <- downloadHandler(
    #specify a filename to save
    filename = function(){
      tempfile(paste0(input$fieldName_f, 'Report'), tmpdir = tempdir(), fileext = '.html')},    
    content = function(file){
      # Copy the template r markdown file to a temporary directory before processing it
      file.copy('reportF.Rmd', frmd, overwrite = T)
      rmarkdown::render(frmd, output_file = file)
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `filename` should simply be the filename that the user receives.  This should be a string.  Try

```
filename = function(){
    paste0(input$fieldName_f, ' Report')}
```

Note that I also added a space before the word "Report", which is probably what you want.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this before, the server still append the root directory before input$fieldName_f, so e.g. for Paddock1, it shows as ubuntu_toshare_Paddock1 Report.html. Cheers.